# ACF field value not working with page bulider

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-widgets

I created a custom widget with some fields "ACF" plugin, in widget area (dynamic sidebar) it works but when I want to add the widget to a page by page builder (I tested Elementor , Page Builder by SiteOrigin, Themify Builder and Beaver Builder Plugin (Lite Version) ) it doesn't work with none of theme. After update the page the values of fields will be clear! How I can fix this?

Comment: can you please share the code? May be you are using this format `get_field('field_name')` or `the_field('field_name')` which take the second argument as the current page id. So it seems that when you add widget to the elementor or any builder, it take the page id of that page and hopefully those page does not have acf field value. JUST ASSUMPTION BASED ON YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: yes this is my code 
$logo = get_field('footer_logo', 'widget_' . $args['widget_id']);